# Where query in Joomla component - what file do I edit?

Tags: php, component, development, mysql, view

Okay, so I am completely new to Joomla and I am trying to edit the source files of a component I built using [component-creator.com](https://www.component-creator.com/en/).

I have a database which stores different data for multiple different users, and I want to design several views where the logged-in user can view only the data associated with their own user name in the database. Currently, every user can see a listing of the data of every other user in the database, which is unacceptable for security reasons. I assume that I need to somehow retrieve the current session user id and use a WHERE query to filter the list view down to only the database entries associated with that user id.

First off, what files do I need to edit? Component-creator seems to suggest [here](https://www.component-creator.com/wiki/index.php?title=Add_where_clause_to_a_SQL_Joomla_field) that I need to edit *views/students/view.html.php*, while some other forums seem to point to *models/students.php*. *models/students.php* seems to already have several SQL queries with chaining and WHERE clauses, but I wanted to make sure.

Secondly, how do I retrieve and/ or pass the current session user id? Do I somehow need to pass that variable from *views/students/tmpl/default.php*, or can I retrieve it directly from within *models/students.php*?

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've probably gathered already, Joomla is an MVC (model, view controller) content management system, so you're database queries will be located in the model:

```
models/students.php
```

As for current user data, you can get the [current user object](https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object) like so:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

Or if it's the actual session ID you wish to get:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->getId();
```

Both of which you can access in any part of the component, so yes, that includes the model.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! That is helpful. Now I am just struggling with the SQL syntax.

Comment: Ask a new question for that and be sure to show us what the syntax error is and the code causing it